# Add user registration and authentication with React, Redux, and Express

Tags: reactjs, authentication, express, redux

I have a React/redux app using Express and Mongo. I'd like users to be able to sign up for an account however I'm not sure how to get React/Redux to post data to Express. Eventually, I would like to store user account information, like email and password, and then authenticate on that data whenever they visit the site to allow access to specific information.

I can POST from HTML straight to the server but I think I'm missing a few extra steps when using React. This may be where I'm stuck. What is the flow of data from React to Redux to Express. Can anyone shed some light?

My RegisterForm component looks like this:

```js
const RegisterForm = () => {
 return (
  <form 
   method='POST' 
   action='/'
   className="form-group">
    <h1>Sign up!</h1>
    <TextInput placeholder="name" name="name"/>
    <TextInput placeholder="email" name="email"/>
    <TextInput placeholder="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>
 );
};
```

The POST route in Express is pretty generic b/c I wanted to first see if the server is even receiving the request. Sadly, I'm getting the CANNOT/POST message.

```js
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
 console.log('User:', req.body.name);
 res.send('Your sign up was successful!');
});
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the method and action.

There is a click event called onSubmit it will listen to the submit button and the trigger the function called registerHandler.

```
<form 
            onSubmit={registerHandler}
            className="form-group">
```

You can read more here.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html